# How to interact with the browser on Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning Node.Js, I would like to understand how to interact between front-end / backend.

I would do backend --> Front End interaction by sendig data using app.get(), but now, I'd like to understand how can I get variable from Front End to Backend.

Front-ENd. (I want to pass varGetFromFrontend to backend)

```
<html>
<script>
var varGetFromFrontend = 2; // This is variable I want to pass to backend
</script>
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1> This is a test</h1>


</body>
</html>
```

On Node.Js  (backend)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = new express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
     var entries = [
        {"id":1, "title":"Hello World!"},
        {"id":2, "title":"Hello World!"}
        {"id":3, "title":"Hello World!"}
        {"id":4, "title":"Hello World!"}
        ];
if(entries.id == varGetFromFrontend){
console.log("This is to print a variable by choosing it from Front End")
 console.log(varGetFromFrontend)
}

var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 5000);
app.listen(port);
```

I would like to know how can I print "varGetFromFrontend" on server side

Comment: Exactly as you would any other serverside language, with page loads, ajax or sockets. Node is just a webserver (in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Make an HTTP request to the server. Include the variable in the request.

There are lots of ways to do this:

Put it in a hidden input in a form, then submit the form.

*or*

Set `location.href` to a new value and include the variable in it (e.g. in a query string)

*or*

Use the `XMLHttpRequest` object to make an HTTP request

*or*

Create a `script` element and include the variable in the URL for the `src` attribute

(This is a non-exhaustive list)

Answer (score 0):

You can interact with the nodejs server from the browser with `socket.io`

First, install socket.io:

```
npm install socket.io
```

and write these code to their respective filenames.

app.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var http = require("http");
var socketIO = require("socket.io");

var app = express();
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendfile("./index.html");
});

var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = socketIO.listen(server, {log: false});
io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket){
    socket.on("sendVar", function(value){
        console.log("The value of the variable is " + value);
    });
});

server.listen(5000);
```

index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Index Page</title>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var variableFromFrontEnd = 2;
        var socket = io.connect("/");
        socket.on("connect", function(){
            console.log("connected!")
            socket.emit("sendVar", variableFromFrontEnd);
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

and run it.

Comment: I couldn't load "socket.io.js" from html code.  Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined

Answer (score -1):

Check out the MEAN framework I built: http://mean.wolframcreative.com/

This uses Node as the back-end server utilizing Express as the API router. The front-end uses angular and is purely an api consumption tool.

Short answer is this:

in angular:

```
$http
    .get('/api/users/bobsaget')
    .success(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

in node(with express):

```
app.get('/api/users/:username', function (req, res) {
    var variable = req.params.username;
    //do logic here with the database(mongo) to get user info:
    db.users.findOne({username: username}, function (error, response) {
        if (!error) {
            res.send(200, response);
        } else {
            res.send(500, {success: false, message: error.message});
        }
    });
)};
```

Long answer is to play around with my framework and get your hands dirty.

Answer (score -1):

I'm currently working on a restful framework for node call snooze. I'm writing an api along side it and it's going very well. The framework is written to be modular and easy to use. Everything is built around modules, routes, controllers, services, and validators.

https://github.com/iamchairs/snooze

```
snooze.module('myServer', ['snooze-stdlib']) // inject the snooze-stdlib module
    .route('get', '/users/:username', { // define the route
        controller: 'UserCtrl', // what controller should handle this route
        action: 'getUserByUsername', // what action to perform on this route
        validator: 'GetUsername' // before processing this action what validation should occur
    })
    .controller('UserCtrl', function(User) { // inject the User service
        return {
            getUserByUsername: function(res, options) {
                User.getUserByUsername(options.query.username).then(function(username) {
                    res.send(200, username);
                }).fail(function(err) {
                    res.send(500, err);
                });
            }
        };
    })
    .service('User', function($q) { // inject the $q service
        return {
            getUserByUsername: function() {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                deferred.resolve('iamchairs');

                return deferred.promise;
            }
        };
    })
    .validator('GetUsername', function($validator) { // inject the validator service
        return function(deferred, req) {
            if($validator.isLength(req.query.username, 2, 32)) {
                deferred.resolve(); // resolve (valid request)
            } else {
                deferred.reject([400, 'Username must be between 2 and 32 characters']); // reject (invalid request)
            }
        }
    });
```